# How to make a JFrame non displayable?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I know there are many questions describing the transparency of `JFrame`. But I've applied them all and an exception is thrown saying:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: 
     The frame is displayable.
```

How to make a `JFrame` not to be displayable?

Comment: read Oracle tutorial for working code example

Comment: I have done it with following code. But I don't know what does it do? It's just a copy paste... It works but can someone tell me what does it actually do??
        

        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                MainFrame obj=new MainFrame();
                
                try{
                obj.setOpacity(0.4f);
                }catch(Exception e){}
            }
        });

Answer (score 2):

Set the transparency before the frame is ever displayed.

Comment: transpaerncy is set but still gives frame displayed

Comment: For more help, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score 1):

This is a quite much discussed topic . I often like to add transparency to my undecorated JFrames. Here is how I do it

```
public class view extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public view() {           
       initComponents();
       mainPanel.setOpaque(false);
       setUndecorated(true);
       setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
       setLocationRelativeTo(null);
       setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This gives a transparent JFrame . I recommend to use a `un-opaque JPanel` on it.

Comment: I have done it with following code. But I don't know what does it do? It's just a copy paste... It works but can someone tell me what does it actually do?? 


JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true); SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { 
       @Override public void run() {
                MainFrame obj=new MainFrame(); 
                try{
                      obj.setOpacity(0.4f);
                }
                catch(Exception e){} 
           } 
  });